# Rotating PDF's with PDFtk

Tags: graphics, pdf

When one rotates any image by 90 degrees and then 90 degrees again one gets an upside down image, and when rotating by two 180 in sequence get back the original image, but NOT in PDFtk.

Rotating an image in PDF format with PDFtk, twice sequentially, as in:

```
pdftk A.pdf cat 1south output Ar.pdf
pdftk Ar.pdf cat 1south output Arr.pdf
```

get you back something that is still 180 rotated. Why?

Comment: Perhaps a little off topic? Maybe there is something I'm missing.

Comment: `pdftk` is a useful tool for post-processing PDF files generated by TeX or for pre-processing PDF files for image inclusion in TeX files.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Indeed. And some of us have no idea what to replace it with now it is disappearing from the world. The wrappers around `pdfpages` really don't cut it. (I could do that myself!) :(

Comment: @AFeldman It is borderline, I guess. But questions about helper tools are generally allowed and `pdftk` is indispensable if you generate PDF. At least, I find it so.

Comment: @cfr ok, well I certainly don't mind, I use `pdftk` all the time.

Comment: @cfr `pdftk` is "disappearing from the world"???

Comment: @AFeldman It is no longer maintained. It is already not available through package managers such as Fedora's. Of course, you can build it but only for as long as the code continues to work with updated versions of its dependencies or you can fix it yourself.

Comment: @cfr sorry to hear that, and thanks for the news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `pdftk --help`:

> The page rotation setting can cause `pdftk` to rotate pages and
>   documents.  Each option sets the page rotation as follows (in
>   degrees): north: 0, east: 90, south: 180, west: 270, left:
>   -90, right: +90, down: +180. left, right, and down make relative adjustments to a page's rotation.

`north`, `east`, `south`, `west` are absolute specifications of the `/Rotate` key in the page's dictionary, whereas `left`, `right`, and `down` are relative to the current setting.

Thus, the following sequence gets you back to the beginning:

```
pdftk A.pdf cat 1down output Ar.pdf
pdftk Ar.pdf cat 1down output Arr.pdf
```

`south`, however, always sets `/Rotate 180`, independently from the current setting.